# How might I create an arrow crossing over text?

Tags: formatting, arrows

[image]

I would like to position arrows next to text/through text like this, is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You could use ti*k*z for drawing the arrows. On texample you can find similar [code](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/) with ti*k*z and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of possibilities, here is one of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$%\tikznodestyle 
  #2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\begin{document}
 $\tikznode{Al}{\textcolor{cyan}{\text{Al}}}^{\tikznode{3p}{\scriptstyle
 \textcolor{cyan}{3+}}}
 \quad\tikznode{O}{\textcolor{red}{\text{O}}}^{\tikznode{2m}{\textcolor{red}{\scriptstyle
2-}}}_{\tikznode{dummy}{\phantom{x}}}
 \longrightarrow
 \text{\textcolor{cyan}{Al}}_{\textcolor{red}{2}}\textcolor{red}{\text{O}}_{\textcolor{cyan}{3}}$
 \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
 \draw[-latex] (3p)--(dummy.center);
 \draw[-latex] (2m)--(Al.south east);
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Just a question, if I add like a blank suffix next to the O so that the arrow extends out a little more, what part of the text would I edit to select the reference characters?

Comment: @Wertea I made an update. If you want to shorten the arrow from `2-` to `Al`, just draw this arrow with `\draw[-latex,shorten >=2pt] (2m)--(Al.south east);`, say.

Answer (score 1):

Does this look like what you like

> [image: equation with arrow crossing]

Here is the code

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} %% Includes arrow head styles.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) node[blue,left=0.02cm] {$\mathrm{Al^{3 +}}$}; %% write the Al ion
\draw (0,0) node[red,left=0.02cm] {$\mathrm{O^{2 -}}$}; %% write the O ion
\draw (3,0) node[left=0.02cm] {$\mathrm{{\color{blue}Al}_{{\color{red}2}} {\color{red}O}_{\color{blue}3}}$}; %% write the product
\draw [-{Stealth[round,scale=1.5]}] (-0.5 , 0.06) -- (-2.4 , -0.17); %% Arrow from O ion to Al ion.
\draw [-{Stealth[round,scale=1.5]}] (-2.15 , 0.06) --(-0.5 , -0.13); %% arrow from Al ion to O ion
\draw [-{Stealth[round,scale=1.5]}] (0 , 0) -- (1.7 , 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

The order of `\draw` in the code is the actual order of drawing, which means the latter ones would be on top of the previous.